# Como hacer que no puedan ingresar letras letras en donde se pide números

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy aprendiendo python he hice un código muy básico pero al probarlo si coloco en el input alguna letra manda un error como puedo hacer que no puedan meter letras

```
while (True):
print("""Bienvendido en que te puedo ayudar
1) Quiero una Suma
2) Quiero una Resta
3) Quiero una Multiplicacion
4) Salir""")
opcion =input()
if opcion =="1":
    n1=float(input("Inserta el primer numero: "))
    n2=float(input("Inserta el segundo numero: "))
    print("El Resultado de la suma es: ",n1+n2)
elif opcion=="2":
    m1=float(input("Inserta el primer numero: "))
    m2=float(input("Inserta el segundo numero: "))
    print("El Resultado de la resta es: ",m1+m2)
elif opcion=="3":
    b1=float(input("Inserta el primer numero: "))
    b2=float(input("Inserta el segundo numero: "))
    print("El Resultado de la multiplicacion es: ",b1+b2)
elif opcion=="4":
    print("Que pases un buen dia")
    break
else:
    print("El Numero introduccido es erroneo")
```

Agradezco sus comentarios y su ayuda de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hay forma, al menos sencilla, de evitar que el usuario introduzca cualquier caracter en un `input`. Lo que puedes hacer es verificar si la entrada del usuario es un numero.

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, por ejemplo usando bloques `try - except`, pero en este caso propongo usar una función, `check_float()` que [verifica si un string se compone de solo números](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32453110/1545868) (SO en inglés), puede tener negativo y punto. Si no es así, entonces vuelve al principio del ciclo `while` a través de un `continue`. De lo contrario sigue y se realizan las operaciones.

```
def check_float(str_input):
    # Verifica un string compuesto de numeros. Devuelve True si es, de lo contrario False.
    return str_input.lstrip('-').replace('.','',1).isdigit()

while (True):
    print("""Bienvendido en que te puedo ayudar
    1) Quiero una Suma
    2) Quiero una Resta
    3) Quiero una Multiplicacion
    4) Salir""")
    opcion = input()
    if opcion == '4':
        break
    if opcion in ['1', '2', '3']:
        n1 = input("Inserta el primer numero: ")
        n2 = input("Inserta el segundo numero: ")
        if (check_float(n1) and check_float(n2)) == False:
            print("Error, al menos una de las entradas no es un numero")
            continue
        if opcion == "1":
            print("El Resultado de la suma es: ", float(n1) + float(n2))
        elif opcion == "2":
            print("El Resultado de la resta es: ",float(n1) - float(n2))
        elif opcion == "3":
            print("El Resultado de la multiplicacion es: ",float(n1) * float(n2))
    else:
        print("El Numero introduccido es erroneo")
```

Answer (score 1):

quizá ya es muy tarde pero, puede que a alguien mas le sirva.
tengo este ejemplo de "menú" con validación de try,exept.
a mi me parece simple y funcional
yo no soy el autor si no mi profesor **Antonio Arias** es su nombre, espero te sirva (lo edite un poco)

```
 opcion = 0

 while (opcion != 5):
    if (opcion == 1):
        print ('opcion 1')

    if (opcion == 2):
        print ('opcion 2')

    if (opcion == 3):
        print ('opcion 3')

    if (opcion == 4):
        print ('opcion 4')
        
    print('\n-TITULO-\n')
    print('1) opcion 1')
    print('2) opcion 2')
    print('3) opcion 3')
    print('4) opcion 4')
    print('5) salir')
    try:
        opcion = int(input('ingrese una opcion: '))
    except:
        print('ingrese una opcion valida')

print ('\n\----------Ha salido del sistema----------\n')
```